# Phonegap Android screen.height and screen.width returning black system bar space

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, device-width

I develop apps with Phonegap for Android.

In some of those apps I use javascript to make some dynamic calculations and place elements on screen.

The app uses Fullscreen preference in config.xml

So far that has been working well, but today I noticed that one app content went behind the black android system bar at bottom (the one with the back button, etc). And if I turn landscape, it also goes behind the bar.

Inspecting, I found that in landscape mode, for example, screen.width is returning 640 for my device, when before it used to return 620. So it looks like now it is including the system bar space?

How can I detect if the value includes the system bar space or not? And how can I know how much space the system bar takes?

The app behavior changed without recompiling it. So something external affected its behavior. Some days ago, the phone had an Android update. Maybe it is related to this.

The phone is using Android 5.0.2. After it upgraded to Android 5.0.2, it was working well. Then there was another, smaller update but it did not change the Android version number. The device is Moto G.

Thanks for any help on this. I really need to be able to get the screen width and height without the space used by that system bar, as it had always been until now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have this issue ?
If you have screen problems with an additional bar at the bottom, you can detect it with

```
$("body").height() != window.screen.height/window.devicePixelRatio
```

From here I am trying to trigger something that will remove the additional bar. Reload / redraw / etc ...